# Error page customization in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to customize the error pages using springboot 1.4.2. I've put my error pages in `src\main\resources\public\error` as mentionned in [the spring boot doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling-custom-error-pages).

But when there is a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` the error page is still the default :

[image: error page]

instead of my `404.html` page

My 404.html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
<title>Erreur 404</title>

<link
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: "Maven Pro";
}

a {
    color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-bottom: transparent 1px solid;
    transition: border-color .05s;
}

section {
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 700px;
    background-color: #444;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 25px;
    color: #eee;
}

.main {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.code {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.fa-exclamation-triangle {
    font-size: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
        <div>
            Le fichier demandé
            <div class="main">n'existe pas</div>
            à cette adresse.
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="code">
            Réponse code <b>404</b>
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="history.back(-1)"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
            Retour page précédente</a><br /> <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            Retour à l'accueil</a><br />
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Info : I run it from STS

Comment: if you are using maven then do a maven clean install after adding the file in resource folder

Comment: @Jobin Thanks for the advice. I've done it but it doesn't work better

Comment: @jayjaypg22 It sounds like you're doing it properly.  Can you share a sample project on GitHub?

Comment: @jayjaypg22 Can you post the code where you are referring src\main\resources\public\error\page.html in your spring config file?

Comment: Seems that your 404.html is not in place where Spring expects it. Are you sure it is in `target/resources/public/error` - if running from IDE or in the jar on that path if running from jar ?

Comment: @dev-null : I run it from STS. Indeed 404.htm is not in target/resources/public/error but really in <MyProject>\src\main\resources\public\error. In order to test I've put 404.html in target/resources/public/error but it doesn't work better

Comment: What do you mean "it is not in target/resources/public/error but really in <MyProject>\src\main\resources\public\error" ? @dev-null is talking about your build, not your sources. Your 404.html file has to be in "<MyProject>\src\main\resources\public\error" in your sources. It has to be in "public\error" (under a "target" directory if u are using M2E plugin) in your build directory.

Comment: @Tristan In my build 404.html is in \target\classes\public\error

Comment: Sound like a build problem. Well I recommend you to build a jar and run it as `java -jar {name-of-your-jar}`. If the problem still persist examine the jar if the file is really there.

Comment: @dev-null : I've done it and run it with the command : `nohup java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod  -jar ../lib/myApp-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8992 --server.session.timeout=60 &` and I still have the same 404 error page

Comment: Extract or look into jar to check if there is `public/error/404.html' file in the root of the jar.

Comment: @dev-null : in the jar the path to 404.html is `BOOT-INF\classes\public\error\`